# Will macOS internet recovery remove my Linux Install?

Tags: linux, mac, partitioning, partition-recovery

I own a MacBook Pro from 2009 and I recently installed Linux on it (with a swap and / partition).

I recently made the stupid mistake of messing with partitions, which caused macOS 10.13 to stop appearing in the boot menu.

To solve that wanted to try the internet recovery that could probably solve that, but I am not sure if it is going to damage my Linux and Linux swap partition.

Can anybody tell me if I am going to lose any data?

Or can I somehow make that partition bootable again from the Linux OS?

NOTE: My Linux partition still works and appears in the menu. But macOS doesn't; it did before.

Comment: A 2009 Mac can't use Internet Recovery. What happens if you boot holding Cmd/R ?

Comment: the Internet recovery screen appears(Starting internet recovery this may take a while...)

Comment: Nothing from 2009 is capable of Internet Recovery. It's just not in the firmware before 2011. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/383985/which-macs-support-macos-internet-recovery for a list. Once you can get to any kind of recovery, use Terminal & add the result of `diskutil list` to your question [select & use Ctrl/K (not Cmd, Ctrl) to format it as `code` which will make it readable in SE]